# How to create pagination on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi all I am a new of wordpress,I want to create pagination next and previous, I have problame with pagination next and previous, I cant find the way to do it.I try to hard to do it, but still can not, How can I do it , Help me please. thanks you.
here is my code page_movie.php

```
<?php 
       global $wpdb;
       $lastedate = $wpdb->get_var("
       SELECT substr(meta_value,1,7) as Date
       FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta 
       WHERE meta_key = 'details_release_date' 
       AND meta_value <> ''
       AND meta_value >= '".date('Y-m-d')."' 
       GROUP BY substr(meta_value,1,7) 
       ORDER BY substr(meta_value,1,7) ASC
       LIMIT 1
       ");                      
      _e(do_shortcode('[movies limit="-1" type="Now Showing"]')); 
      _e(do_shortcode('[movies limit="-1" type="Coming Soon" compare="BETWEEN" start="'.date('Y-m-d').'" end="'.$lastedate.'-31"]')); 
     _e(do_shortcode('[movies limit="-1" type="Released" compare="BETWEEN"  start="'.date('Y').'-01-01" end="'.date('Y-m-d').'"]'));
      ?>
<?php the_posts_pagination( $lastedate ); ?>
```

Comment: You will need WP_query and get_query_var

Comment: can you help me bro, do it ?

Comment: I am try many way but still not work.

Comment: did you go to the link in the answer?